# SOAP request URI no being created correctly in Java

Tags: java, http, url, soap, http-headers

I am trying to find out why the HTTP headers on my SOAP request are not turning out valid. I have a SOAPMessage which I try to send:

```
SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection.call(soapMessage, new URL("http", HOST_URL_NO_PORT, SERVER_PORT,
                    PAGE_NAME));
```

And the values are (for example):

```
private static final Integer SERVER_PORT = 1234; 
private static final String HOST_URL_NO_PORT = "server.domain.comp";
private static final String PAGE_NAME = "com.webservice/services/" +
            "myservice";
```

I know the xml section of the SOAPMessage is fine since when I place into SoapUI it works fine. But when I sniff using *WireShark* the http header's full server URI looks like:

```
http://server.domain.comp:1234http://server.domain.comp:1234/com.webservice/services/myservice
```

When the one from SoapUI looks like

```
http://server.domain.comp:1234/com.webservice/services/myservice
```

Why is it adding the host twice? I have tried just passing in the straight URI as a String too but it still does the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this. Not sure if it was IntelliJ or the actual JDK. Might have been using a bad JDK or trying for an earlier java compatibility (like 1.5 or something).

But I swapped my project JDK from 1.7 to 1.8. And it works